# Has anyone tried/had trouble with being able to build the Redbeard "Pages" tutorial project?

Tags: objective-c, redbeard-ios

If I download the source and build it works fine, but if I do it myself Xcode won't find the default.inc.json file. If I alter the path to /default-theme/default.inc.json then that particular file is found, but other theme files aren't

Clearly, for some reason my set up is causing grief. However, analysing the directory structure of my app and the source comes up with no differences.

Has anyone run into the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to set the 'root' theme file? If so it should be named 'theme.inc.json'. From there you should add in your own theme files and include files.

See this for further information about themes and the general structure. http://redbeard.io/documentation/theme-reference

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem.

The problem was when one drags the 'default-theme' folder into the project.

A window will appear asking how you want to add the files: make sure "Copy items if needed" is checked, and "Create groups" is selected. Important: do not choose "Create folder references" otherwise your project will not work.

The example now works as documented.